# Getting electrocutioners gloves after missing them the first time

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I'm playing Arkham Origins on PC, and after I knocked out Electrocutioner I didn't take his gloves...didn't see a way too.

I'm up to defeating copperhead..at least that's my mission objective, although I can't find her. I thought I would deal with Riddlers towers, but am  up to the one where I need the gloves to get rid of the disrupter.

I went back to Penguins ship, but I can't get back to the theater where I knocked out Electrocutioner. I remember Alfred saying something about him being on the move again and being able to track him, but I can't find any indication on my map.

How can I find him and get the shock gloves?

Comment: I went back to the Electrocutioner lying on the ground, but Batman just ignored him, he didn't even try to tie the guy's arms. Later he was surprised to learn that the Electrocutioner managed to escape the police. So much for the so-called "World's best detective".

Answer (score 2):

You get the shock gloves at a later point in the story, there is no way to get his gloves while on the ship.

Location of the gloves:

> The hotel.

Comment: Then I have no idea where to go in the story now. My objective is to defeat copperhead...but as far as I know I have.

Comment: @Jen: If you're going after Copperhead, you need to go to the steel mill in the industrial district.

Comment: @JeffMercado I've been through the steel mill, thought Copeprhead and won...and went back outside the steel mill. My objective is still defeat Copeprhead...so I'm thinking it's a glitch.

Comment: @Jen: I don't remember the exact chain of events for that mission but I remember Batman tying Copperhead up and throwing him/her into a truck/crate, signifying the end. It should have happened right after you got the antidote IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

Go back where you first fought Copper Head. This happened to me, and after going back I was able to continue my story.